# OleDbParameterCollection has no constructor defined

Tags: c#, oledb

In my project, I have a DBAdapter class that deals with database queries.

```
public class DBAdapter
{
    private OleDbConnection _connection;

    private void _Connect()
    {
        this._connection = new OleDbConnection();
        _connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Accessconnection"];
        _connection.Open();
    }

    private void _Disconnect()
    {
        _connection.Close();
    }


    public DataTable Select(string query, OleDbParameterCollection parameters = null)
    {

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        query = "SELECT " + query;

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (OleDbParameter parameter in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
        }

        this._Connect();
        cmd.Connection = _connection;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        if (parameters != null)  {
            cmd.Prepare();
        }
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "results");
        this._Disconnect();

        dataTable = dataSet.Tables["results"];
        return dataTable;
    }

}
```

In order to perform prepared queries, the Select method has an optionnal OleDBParameterCollection parameter. 
Then, I have multiple Mappers for each domain object in my project, for example UserMapper, that use DataAdapter class to run queries (for example find user by id).

```
    public class UserMapper : DataMapperAbstract
        {

            public User findByID(int id)
            {
                User user = new User()
                string query = "* FROM USER WHERE idUser = ?";
                OleDbParameterCollection parameters = new OleDbParameterCollection();
                parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("idUser", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id);

                // Prepared query
                DataTable results = adapter.Select(query, parameters);
                this._populateData(user, results.Rows[0]);
                return user;
            }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I have an error at this line

```
   OleDbParameterCollection parameters = new OleDbParameterCollection();
```

VS says that the type OleDbParameterCollection has no constructor defined, and I don't really understand what is the problem here. Maybe I don't have rights to instantiate OleDbParameterCollection, but in that case, how should I pass a collection of parameters to my DBAdapter's method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OleDbParameterCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't expose public constructor we can access. It doesn't meant to be used that way so, simply change your method parameter to accept list of `OleDbParameter` instead of `OleDbParameterCollection` :

```
public DataTable Select(string query, List<OleDbParameter> parameters = null)
{
}
```

Then use it accordingly :

```
List<OleDbParameter> parameters = new List<OleDbParameter>();
parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("idUser", OleDbType.Integer){ Value = id });

// Prepared query
DataTable results = adapter.Select(query, parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks it works fine, except that the Add method doesn't accept the ".Value=id" part". Is there a way to set value of the parameter on the same line without writing "parameters[index].value=x" for each parameter ?

Comment: try using object initializer syntax : `new OleDbParameter("idUser", OleDbType.Integer){ Value = id }`

Answer (score 0):

OleDbParameterCollection has no public constructors.

When the OleDbDataAdapter object is instantiated it automatically creates an OleDbParameterCollection object for you within the SelectCommand object.

Here is some code from MSDN that I found:

> ```
> OleDbDataAdapter adapter =
> new OleDbDataAdapter(queryString, connection);
> // Set the parameters.
> adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(
>         "@CategoryName", OleDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = "toasters";
> ```

Here is the link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx

You may need to modify the way you run the query a little bit. But, it looks like you've already got an adapter object in there, so it shouldn't be too hard.